# Poor performance on Quicksort, Dual Pivot, Many equal keys

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

I have an issue with the performance of quicksort concerning the dual pivoting strategy.

The situation:

Take an array a of `n` randomly generated 32-bit integers and bring these in ascending order. Lets fix `n = 10_000_000` and let the random numbers be generated in `[0,MAX_RAND]`. Here everything works as expected - the performance of my implementation is comparable the one of the `qsort()` library implementation.

Now the problem:

Taking the same `n` as above but restricting the intervall for the random-numbers to `[0,K] where K < ~5000`, the performance breaks down dramatically. Some numbers from my machine:

K = MAX_RAND
QS-DUAL-PIVOT Time: 865ms
Ascending:          1
QS_LIBRARY Time:    1296ms
Ascending:          1

K = 10000
QS-DUAL-PIVOT Time: 2521ms
Ascending:          1
QS_LIBRARY Time:    1076ms
Ascending:          1

K = 5000
QS-DUAL-PIVOT Time: 4420ms
Ascending:          1
QS_LIBRARY Time:    1044ms
Ascending:          1

I think, you get the idea. Its compiled on my private intel machine with gcc-5.2 under Arch-Linux-64 with -O9.

Do you have any hints for me? Whats the problem here?

Example code to generate the above outputs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int is_ascending (int *arr, int size)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i ++)
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
            return 0;

    return 1;
}


void quick_sort_dual_pivot (int *arr, int low, int high)
{
    int lt, ht, i, temp;

    if (low >= high)
        return;

    lt = low + 1;
    ht = high - 1;

    if (arr[low] > arr[high])
        {
        temp      = arr[low];
        arr[low]  = arr[high];
        arr[high] = temp;
        }

    if (low + 1 == high)
        return;

    for (i = low + 1; i <= high; ++i)
        {
        if (i > ht)
            break;

        if (arr[i] < arr[low])
            {
            temp = arr[lt];
            arr[lt] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
            ++lt;
            }
        else if (arr[i] > arr[high])
            {
            temp = arr[ht];
            arr[ht] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
            --ht;
            --i;
            }
        }

    ++ht;
    temp      = arr[ht];
    arr[ht]   = arr[high];
    arr[high] = temp;

    --lt;
    temp     = arr[lt];
    arr[lt]  = arr[low];
    arr[low] = temp;

    quick_sort_dual_pivot (arr, low, lt - 1);
    quick_sort_dual_pivot (arr, lt + 1, ht - 1);
    quick_sort_dual_pivot (arr, ht + 1, high);
}

int get_ms (int start)
{
    static struct timeval start_time;
           struct timeval end_time;
    int msec, seconds, useconds;

    if (start)
        {
        gettimeofday (&start_time, NULL);

        return 0;
        }

    gettimeofday (&end_time, NULL);

    seconds  = end_time.tv_sec  - start_time.tv_sec;
    useconds = end_time.tv_usec - start_time.tv_usec;

    msec = ((seconds) * 1000 + useconds / 1000.) + 0.5;

    return msec;
}


int comp_asc (const void *arg1, const void *arg2)
{
     return (*(int *)arg1) - (*(int *)arg2);
}


#define ARRAY_SIZE 10000000

int main(void)
{
   int i;
   int millisec;
   static int a1[ARRAY_SIZE];
   static int a2[ARRAY_SIZE];

   srand (time (NULL));

   for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i ++)
       {
       int r = rand () % 5000;
       a1[i] = r;
       a2[i] = r;
       }

   get_ms (1);
   quick_sort_dual_pivot (a1, 0, ARRAY_SIZE - 1);
   millisec = get_ms (0);
   printf ("QS-DUAL-PIVOT Time: %dms\n", millisec);
   printf ("Ascending:          %d\n", is_ascending (a1, ARRAY_SIZE));
   get_ms (1);
   qsort (a2, ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof (int), comp_asc);
   millisec = get_ms (0);
   printf ("QS_LIBRARY Time:    %dms\n", millisec);
   printf ("Ascending:          %d\n", is_ascending (a2, ARRAY_SIZE));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well did some profiling and what i can tell you by now is, that the number of calls to `quick_sort_dual_pivot` is nearly identical with/without duplicate numbers, but the execution time per call is significantly higher with the duplicates... not yet looked into the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest one optimization to your algorithm.

There are instances, where `arr[lt] == arr[ht]` after grouping and before recursion in which case the whole array part 2 contains duplicates of the same element. This particular case makes the algorithm really slow, since the boundaries are only narrowed by 2 for each recursive step. Also, the situation is easily avoided by changing the recursion part a bit:

```
quick_sort_dual_pivot(arr, low, lt - 1);
if (arr[lt] != arr[ht])
    quick_sort_dual_pivot(arr, lt + 1, ht - 1);
quick_sort_dual_pivot(arr, ht + 1, high);
```

For me at least it led to a considerable speedup.

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20917901/5265292) helped me alot in understanding the Dual Pivot Quicksort and contains an illustration, that shows what I mean with things like "Part 2". Also, in the comments the same optimization that I suggest here is mentioned (though I didn't read it there before discovering it myself^^)

See the following times for the comparison between your version and the enhancement (QS-DUAL-PIVOT2)

With `int r = rand();`:

> QS-DUAL-PIVOT Time: 2216ms
>
> Ascending:          1
>
> QS-DUAL-PIVOT2 Time: 640ms
>
> Ascending:          1

With `int r = rand() % 5000;`:

> QS-DUAL-PIVOT Time: 11185ms
>
> Ascending:          1
>
> QS-DUAL-PIVOT2 Time: 530ms
>
> Ascending:          1

As you can see, my machine has a higher basis time of execution, so I am curious how well it optimizes for your case.

Answer (score 1):

The results are amazing! I also added the insertion-sort twist and now see the following results:

```
int r = rand ();
```

> QS-DUAL-PIVOT Time:  875ms
>   QS-DUAL-PIVOT2 Time: 847ms
>   QS-LIBRARY Time:     1289ms

```
int r = rand () % 10000;
```

> QS-DUAL-PIVOT Time:  2511ms
>   QS-DUAL-PIVOT2 Time: 513ms
>   QS-LIBRARY Time:     1080ms

```
int r = rand () % 5000;
```

> QS-DUAL-PIVOT Time:  4399ms
>   QS-DUAL-PIVOT2 Time: 475ms
>   QS-LIBRARY Time:     1043ms

Of course, the comparison with the library function is not accurate at the moment, because I have to generalize the datatype for my implementation. But still, these results are quite promising.

Comment: So, you used my suggestion, added a fallback algorithm and improved the benchmark section? Fine, you get your +1 so you may be allowed to write comments in the near future :)

Comment: a follow-up to the issue you raised about sorted sequences: I experimented a bit with a mixin: the pivot elements P1 and P2 mark the upper and lower bound of part 2. So instead of randomizing the pivots, I decided to handle part 2 with a traditional 2-partition quicksort step where I use the average of P1, P2 as an artificial pivot element. The two partitions are then in turn sorted by `quick_sort_dual_pivot`. On average cases it performs as good as the pure dual pivot and for sorted cases it performs only slightly worse than for randoms.