# What are the disadvantages of Dual-Pivot Quicksort?

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

I know that it has fewer swaps and is faster than the classic Quicksort but I can't seem to see any disadvantages of this algorithm.

Comment: Vintage assessment of sorting algorithms stresses number of (array) assignments and number of key comparisons: what can you say about the latter?

Answer (score 3):

Dual-pivot quicksort is more complicated than the original. The extra pivot requires the two pivots to be compared and swapped if needed. There is an extra index into the array, an extra case for moving an element, and an extra swap at the end.

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: @riverphoenix [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917617/whats-the-difference-of-dual-pivot-quick-sort-and-quick-sort/20917901#20917901) is a good answer about it.

Answer (score 0):

In general more the number of pivots, better is the performance and again the choice of the pivot matters a lot for any quick sort algorithm. Refer: [study](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1757-899X/180/1/012051/pdf)

Badly chosen pivots for dual-pivot will perform worse than a normal quick sort with good pivot. The choice of pivot is highly dependent on the data set. Again, for complex data sets choosing more pivots properly can become hard.

Comment: (Why would multi-pivot quicksort start to look like a bucket sort with non-uniform bucket size?)