# What is the name of this sorting method, how does it work and how does it compare to Arrays.sort()?

Tags: java, sorting, linear-search

### Q#1

I am searching for a method to sort an array in *ascending* order. I found this and it works, but I don't understand *how* it works.

### Q#2

As for the Big O notation, which method is better (`n` will be small in my case), the method below or `Arrays.sort()`?

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < array; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < array; j++) {
      if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
         order = arr[j];
         arr[j] = arr[i];
         arr[i] = order;
      }
    }
}
```

**Note:** `array` is equal to `arr.length`.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean: "...to sort an array in **descending** order..."?

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community! Could you tag the post with the language you are using? This makes it easier to find and answer the question.

Comment: @JanezKuhar yes i have tried both this way is for the ascending from little to big can you tell me how does it work. because i am trying to it kind a hard

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for the hint, i am now reading about both of sorting bubble and insertion. 
now is it better to have Arrays,sort() or in the way up there. cause even though this method is o(n^2) it is quicker in measuring nano seconds, that is why i was wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### #1

The method you are using is closest to what is called a [Selection Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). A nice illustration can be found [here](https://www.w3resource.com/php-exercises/searching-and-sorting-algorithm/searching-and-sorting-algorithm-exercise-4.php) and a more entertaining one [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ns4TPTC8whw).

A proper implementation of a selection sort would start the inner loop at `j = i + 1` and swap at most one element per each iteration of the outer loop (the *minimum* or *maximum* of elements in the unsorted part of the array with the `i-th` element). As it stands, the array still gets sorted correctly, but you are doing a lot of redundant comparisons and swaps.

Also note that your `if` logic sorts the array in **descending** order (and not in **ascending**, as you claim that it does).

#### #2

The time complexity of a Selection Sort is `O(n^2)`, whereas `Arrays.sort()` uses [Dual Pivot Quicksort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20917901/6367213) with an `O(nlogn)` time complexity. There is also an optimisation built into the JDK's sorting algorithm that uses Insertion Sort on smaller arrays so there really is no reason for you to worry about performance.

---

**Edit:** Why is the sorting time faster using this method as opposed to using `Arrays.sort()`?

While the [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)) state:

> **Implementation Note:**
>
> *The sorting algorithm is a Dual-Pivot Quicksort...*

the [actual implementation](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk14/file/6c954123ee8d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java) is much more involved and contains all kinds of optimisations.

Of course, there can be a particular case where your sorting method is faster, but I would stick to using the JDK's sorting algorithm. It has been thoroughly tested and refined to assure correctness and optimal performance.

Another thing to consider, as @GhostCat has pointed out, is that your benchmarking might be flawed. Check [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/6367213) for more on that topic.

Comment: i was wondering because in the method up there it was giving me less time than Arrays,sort(). anyway thanks for answering second question, I would have voted you up but not much credits.

Comment: @JanezKuhar yes now it is much better, thank u. 
the weird thing that arrays.sort took longer time in array.sort than in nanoTime
array.sort took 282300 in nano and in this method 60200 so i was wondering if this has a relation with big O