# What is worst scenerio of Randomized Quicksort?

Tags: data-structures

I want to know about Worst Scenerio of Randomized Quick sort and its big oh Complexity?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [quicksort worst case condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834740/quicksort-worst-case-condition)

Comment: The linked question isn't about randomized quicksort specifically, but most of the answers apply; the worst case is when the pivot is consistently the smallest or largest element.