# Why is this partial quick sort implementation so much slower than the standard library sort?

Tags: sorting, rust

Obviously, the std library implementation is always going to be far faster than mine, but this takes 3 minutes or so to complete for a 773 x 1031 image on a fast computer. Using the same comparator, the standard library takes 4 seconds to sort the entire image. Any ideas why my code is so slow?

```
fn partial_quick_sort(img: &mut Bitmap, cmp: &BoxedPixelComparator) {
    // buffer is a Vec of Pixel structs - Pixel { r: u8, g: u8, b: u8, a: u8 }
    let max_depth = img.buffer.len()/200;
    println!("{}", max_depth); // For the input image I'm testing with, this prints 3984

    let mut queue = VecDeque::new();
    queue.push_back(img.buffer.as_mut_slice());

    let mut depth = 0;
    loop {
        let buffer_opt = queue.pop_front();
        if buffer_opt.is_none() {
            break;
        }
        let buffer = buffer_opt.unwrap();
        if depth >= max_depth || buffer.len() <= 1 {
            continue;
        }
        let pivot_idx = buffer.len() - 1;

        // cmp is a comparator function, which just compares the sums of two pixels
        let (left, _pivot, right) = buffer.partition_at_index_by(pivot_idx, cmp);
        queue.push_back(left);
        queue.push_back(right);
        depth +=1;
    }

}
```

Comment: blind answer: you forget to use --release ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest problem with the algorithm is this line:

```
let pivot_idx = buffer.len() - 1;
```

Quicksort needs a well-chosen pivot to be efficient: ideally, the pivot should divide the array to be sorted in half. Because you picked a pivot **index** of `n - 1`, you're partitioning each slice into an unsorted prefix of length `n - 1` and a single "sorted" element at the end of the slice (and an empty suffix). [The implementation of `partition_at_index*` actually special cases the `n - 1` case](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/sort.rs.html#783-788), so this algorithm is basically a selection sort, which is O(n²) (see, for example, [quicksort worst case condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4834740/3650362)).

The documentation for [`partition_at_index_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.partition_at_index_by) is a little ambiguous, which may have led you to this error:

> Reorder the slice with a comparator function such that the element at `index` is at its final sorted position.

By "the element at `index`" it means the element that *ends up* at `index`, not the one that *starts* there.

To fix this issue, change the line above to read `buffer.len() / 2`.